# How to sort category by custom field value

Tags: custom-field, categories, meta-value

I am using the following :

```
    $catargs = array(
        'meta_key'=> 'category_custom_order',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'=> 'ASC',

    );
```

but I can get the list of category sorted by the meta value key

[image: image of the category in dashboard]

unfortunately, it still listing the category by title instead.

Is there a better way to do this? thanks for helping.

The complete code:

```
    <?php 
    // Query by category and group
    $catargs = array(
        'meta_key'=> 'category_custom_order',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'=> 'DESC',

    ); 

    $categories = get_categories( $catargs );

    foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <section id="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" class="entry-category">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <h2 class="category-header"><?php echo $category->name;// Category title ?></h2>
        </header>
        <div class="entry-desc"><?php echo $category->description; ?></div>
        <?php // WP_Query arguments
        $args = array (
            'post_type'       => 'post',
            'cat'             => $category->cat_ID,
            'posts_per_page'  => '-1',
            'order'           => 'DESC',
            'orderby'         => 'title',
        );

        // The Query
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post(); ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h3 class="entry-title">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h3>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </article>
        <?php }
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }
            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </section>
    <!-- #<?php echo $category->slug; ?> -->
```

I just want to sort the category by meta key value from the included image.

I am using the function bellow to create a custom field for my categories under the dashboard:

```
    /*
     * Add Custom Field To Category Form 
     */
    add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'category_form_custom_field_add', 10 );
    add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'category_form_custom_field_edit', 10, 2 );

    function category_form_custom_field_add( $taxonomy ) {
    ?>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="category_custom_order">Custom Order</label>
            <input name="category_custom_order" id="category_custom_order" type="text" value="" size="10" aria-required="true" />
            <p class="description">Enter a custom order value.</p>
        </div>
    <?php
    }

    function category_form_custom_field_edit( $tag, $taxonomy ) {
        $option_name = 'category_custom_order_' . $tag->term_id;
        $category_custom_order = get_option( $option_name );
    ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="category_custom_order">Custom Order</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="category_custom_order" id="category_custom_order" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $category_custom_order ) ? esc_attr( $category_custom_order ) : ''; ?>" size="10" aria-required="true" />
                <p class="description">Enter a custom order value.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }

    /** Save Custom Field Of Category Form */
    add_action( 'created_category', 'category_form_custom_field_save', 10, 2 ); 
    add_action( 'edited_category', 'category_form_custom_field_save', 10, 2 );

    function category_form_custom_field_save( $term_id, $tt_id ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['category_custom_order'] ) ) {
            $option_name = 'category_custom_order_' . $term_id;
            update_option( $option_name, $_POST['category_custom_order'] );
        }
    }//end
```

Now what I am looking for is how to order the category list by that custom field value ranging from 1 to 5 in asc order?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Please add your code

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have included the full code. Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: I dont think such feature is available currently. Categories does not have meta feature.

Comment: You are using invalid parameters in `get_categories`. Categories don't have custom fields neither can they even be sorted by any custom field. Your question now makes even less sense than before the edit

Comment: I added a custom field to edit category and now I want to sort category by that custom field. I have added the function that create the custom field for the category.

Comment: @Nilambar does it make sense now based on the new addition of the code that create the custom filed value for categories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort category page with custom field](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10503/sort-category-page-with-custom-field)

Answer (score 3):

Your question it make sense to me my friend but the get_categories don't have the option to order by "meta_value_num" and then order by custom fields.

What you can do is order after you get the array using the usort php function:

```
    $all_subcategories = array('parent' => $categoryID);

    $categories = get_categories( $all_subcategories );

    function order_categories($a, $b) {
    if ($a->term_id == $b->term_id) {
        return 0;
    }
        return ($a->term_id < $b->term_id) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    usort($categories, "order_categories");
```

It work fine for me.  I used ACF to add the category order field but is fine the way you made it and should work.

Answer (score 1):

I know i am late but let it publish for some future developer help...!
Get categories doesn't give the option to sort by meta value num , so you have to do the following thing , just add this in your function file

```php
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'add_category_order_field' );
add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'add_category_order_field' );

function add_category_order_field( $tag ) {
    $cat_order = get_term_meta( $tag->term_id, 'category_order', true ); 
    ?>

    <tr class='form-field'>
        <th scope='row'><label for='category_order'><?php _e( 'Category Order' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='cat_title' id='cat_title' value='<?php echo $cat_order ?>'>
            <p class='description'><?php _e( 'Enter the order value for the category' ); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
};

add_action( 'created_category', 'save_category_order_field' );
add_action( 'edited_category', 'save_category_order_field' );

function save_category_order_field( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['cat_title'] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id , 'category_order', $_POST['cat_title'] );
    }
}
```

After this where your are getting your categories, get the category like this

```php
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'meta_key'   => 'category_order',   //your meta key
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
) );
```

Hope this helps!